# Jquery id not working for more than one link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used jquery to make an id "hover-b" to work only when hovering over an element with an id "hover-a".I add the hover-a id to dropdowns in the navbar and the entire page below the navbar is in a div with the id hover-b.
When the user hovers over a link in navbar using these two ids the entire page below fades and the user's focus is forcefully diverted toward the dropdown list that appears like in some online stores and boutiques such as amazon.com.
Here is my code.

```
$(function(){$("#hover-a").hover(function(){
    $("#hover-b").css("background-color","#222222"),
    $("#hover-b").css("-moz-opacity","0.1"),
    $("#hover-b").css("opacity","0.1"),
    $("#hover-b").css("filter","alpha(opacity=10)")},
function(){$("#hover-b").css("background-color","#ffffff"),
           $("#hover-b").css("-moz-opacity","1.0"),
           $("#hover-b").css("opacity","1.0"),
           $("#hover-b").css("filter","alpha(opacity=100)")})});
```

My problem is that the hover-a id for some reason is not working for more than one of the links in the navbar.
I used jquery because I couldn't find a css solution to link the two ids the way I wanted.
If you can fix my jquery that's awesome but if you have a completely different alternative preferably a css only alternative than that's also much welcome.

I hope I was clear enough in what I am trying to achieve here. Please ignore any bad English. Any help anyone can give is much appreciated. Thanks all in advance.

Comment: where is class here you are using ID?

Comment: _the hover-a class_ `$("#hover-a")` => `$(".hover-a")`

Comment: ok than how do i fix my id problem

Comment: check @Tushar 's comment. replace `$("#hover-a")` with `$(".hover-a")`. Same for `hover-b`

Comment: ok i fixed the question now can we please focus on the problem at hand

Comment: Show the Html code.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use 1 ID per HTML page, this means that on your page, you can have an element with `id="hover-a"` *once and only once*. [IDs are *global* attributes]. [1](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp).

> I add the hover-a id to dropdowns in the navbar

This means you're breaking your HTML page by the same ID more than once. The solution is to simply change all of your `hover-a` from id to class, and use this for your jquery instead:

```
$(".hover-a").hover(function () {
    $(".hover-b").css({
        "background-color": "#222222",
        "-moz-opacity": "0.1",
        "opacity": "0.1",
        "filter": "alpha(opacity=10)",
    });

    $(".hover-b").css({
        "background-color": "#ffffff",
        "-moz-opacity": "1.0",
        "opacity": "1.0",
        "filter": "alpha(opacity=100)"
    });
});
```

what I did on your jquery was change all the IDs to classes and edited all the css properties at once, as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)